# "String data, right truncation" via ODBC but not via SQL Server Manager with the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, perl, odbc

I have a LAPP stack on one server and MSSQL running on another.  The former connects to the latter via Microsoft's [ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160) and generally works well.

One search page of ours fails with the following error if the query string is too long:

```
Couldn't execute statement: [unixODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation (SQL-22001)
```

However, if I copy the query, paste it in a MS SQL Server Manager query window connected to the same database, replace all the `?` placeholders with exactly what my script passes to `$sth->execute()`, and run it, it does not produce an error.

Why is this?  (Does this indicate a bug in the ODBC driver, or SSM, or just a difference between the two?)

Better yet, or I suppose my end goal, would be: how can I get my script to behave like SSM does?  Currently the only fix I can see is to go through every single column (and there are many, it's a union across 5 queries each of which has many table joins) and find out what the length of every varchar column is that the query string might every be too long for, and then differentiate all the placeholders by length.  I.e. I have to do my own truncation and have yet another code dependency--when our database vendor decides to lengthen a column, for example, then I have to go and lessen the truncation in any script the column appears in.  Can't the ODBC driver "just work" the same way SSM does, without complaining?

If I enable tracing, I get one of these per placeholder:

```
-dbd_bind_ph=rebind_param
+rebind_param 7 '%aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa%' (size svCUR=43/SvLEN=48/max=0) svtype:8, value type:1, sql type:0
+get_param_type(7f22ca950e88,7)
  bind 7 '%aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...' value_len=43 maxlen=47 null=0)
  bind 7 value_type:1 VARCHAR cs=20 dd=0 bl=43
-rebind_param
+dbd_bind_ph(7f22ca950e88, name=8, value='%aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa%', attribs=, sql_type=0(unknown), is_inout=0, maxlen=0
  First bind of this placeholder
```

It seems the `cs=...` is what varies and seems to correspond to the maximum placeholder size I could get away with in that context.  Is there a way to access that `cs` value so I can limit the value before I bind it, but dynamically so that I don't have these extra code dependencies?  Perhaps that's what SSM does automagically?

**UPDATE:** I found in the [DBD::ODBC::FAQ under "Why am I getting errors with bound parameters?"](http://search.cpan.org/~mjevans/DBD-ODBC-1.48/FAQ#Why_am_I_getting_errors_with_bound_parameters?) under "data truncated error" a description more or less of this problem.  Is it really true that I'd have to loop through every parameter to fix it to the length returned by `SQLDescribeParam` (minus 2, so I can add '%' signs for searching at the start and end)...but that that's not even guaranteed to work if I use any kind of join because it may get the length wrong?  What's wrong with this picture?

**UPDATE2:** I just found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451.aspx) that, "If you are using the Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux, you should upgrade to the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server."  Off to try that...**UPDATE2.5** on the latest `libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0` driver, it also exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: Is there another updated version of ODBC Driver.. Try to install that might solve the issue.

Comment: The build was `sqlncli-11.0.1790.0` but I don't see anything newer on the ODBC driver team's blog.

Comment: I presume you are using Perl since you said $sth->execute(). If you are and you are using a relatively new DBI and DBD::ODBC then "export DBI_TRACE=DBD=x.log" then run your script. If nothing in x.log change "DBD" to 15 and repeat. What does the log look like around the error? String data right truncated is not likely to be because your sql is long.

Comment: @bohica yes, sorry I forgot the latter P isn't necessarily Perl.  The log looks very verbose, what are you looking for?  I'm not saying the SQL is too long, it's the placeholder data that is too long, like if you put `WHERE COLUMNA LIKE '...'` and make `...` be longer than `COLUMNA` is defined to be.

Comment: Near the end there should be an obvious error (the one you quote). Take a few hundred lines before and after - that should do it. If you don't want to post it here put it on a service like pastebin.com. BTW< I maintain DBD::ODBC.

Comment: @bohica thanks for your help, I posted an example from the trace.

Comment: Sorry but that is not enough log to diagnose the issue. Could you send me (mjevans at cpan dot org) the full log or post is somewhere I can see the full log?

Comment: Sorry I have taken so long to reply - your log sent 14-apr got lost in my inbox. Your log shows you are binding values too large for the columns as you discovered. Was this a select statement? At first the problem you describe seems strange but if you think about it a column of size 30 cannot possibly match a string of length 43 with out without the leading and trailing % chrs. Using a non parameterised query is not the same, it is the binding of placeholders at execution which causes the error. I will reproduce and see what I can find.

Comment: My tests show a parameterised select with a parameter bigger than a varchar column works fine. Can we see your SQL statement that goes with the log you sent me.

Comment: It also may help to see the schema of the tables involved.

Comment: @bohica, I sent the schema and statement now.  About the binding of values too large, that's intentional in the sense that I don't expect those columns to match in that case.  The context is an "easy search" for the user that searches a few relevant columns all at once without them having to choose from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to bohica, DBD::ODBC now exports a function `odbc_describe_param` that exposes the necessary information for a workaround for the uber-text-search situation:

```
# $sth is an already-prepared statement
for (1..(scalar keys %{$sth->{ParamTypes}})) {
    my @help = $sth->odbc_describe_param($_);
    if ($help[1]) { # like SQLDescribeParam API - i.e., type, size, decimal digital and nullable
        $sth->bind_param($_, '%' . substr($s, 0, $help[1] - 2) . '%');
    } else { # 0 = false = unlimited length allowed
        $sth->bind_param($_, '%' . $s . '%');
    }
}
$sth->execute();
...
```